# What are the rules of how "close" to each other variables are stored in C, if any?

Tags: c, memory

I know that for a struct

```
struct sequences{
    int a[3];
    int b[3];
} sequence = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

a and b are stored next to each other, i.e if I do

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<6; ++i){
    printf("%d", sequence.a[i]);
}
```

I will get the output 123456.

I tried storing these two arrays outside of the main function but not in a struct

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int b[3] = {4,5,6};
```

and when I try the same thing,

```
    for(i=0; i<6; ++i){
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }
```

I get the output 123045. So they are obviously not guaranteed to be stored next to each other if not in a struct.

If I instead store an array and a integer after it, they seem to always be after each other in memory, i.e

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int x = 1000;
```

and

```
    for(i=0; i<4; ++i){
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
```

gives 1231000.

I realize that the compiler probably chooses where to store the variables based on some complex factors outside of my control, but are there any rules which **guarantees** where two variables will be stored in relation to each other, like there seems to be for structs?

Comment: What would be the use of such a guarantee, if it existed?

Comment: You should know that there _could_ be a gap between `a` and `b` in your `struct sequences`, and that even if there isn't, accessing `a[3]` through `a[6]` has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard only guarantees that non-bitfield members of a struct are stored sequentially in memory with optional padding between elements, and that members of an array are stored sequentially with no padding.

With regard to structs, section 6.7.2.1p15 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> Within  a  structure  object,  the  non-bit-field  members  and  the 
>   units  in  which  bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in
>   the order in which they are declared.  A pointer to a structure 
>   object,  suitably  converted,  points  to  its  initial  member  (or 
>   if  that  member  is  a bit-field,  then  to  the  unit  in  which  it
>   resides),  and  vice  versa.   There  may  be  unnamed padding within
>   a structure object, but not at its beginning.

There are **no** guarantees regarding the placement of one unrelated variable to another in memory.

Also, when you do this:

```
struct sequences{
    int a[3];
    int b[3];
} sequence = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
...

int i;
for(i=0; i<6; ++i){
    printf("%d", sequence.a[i]);
}
```

You invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you index past the end of the array member `a`.  The implementation is not required to read the elements of `b` in this case.  The best you can to while still conforming to the standard is to compare `&sequence.a[3] == &sequence.b[0]`

Comment: So the fact that an array and an integer, like in my example, seems to always be stored next to each other is a pure coincidence? Is it efficient to store them this way?

Comment: @Stupid Yes it is coincidence.  If you were to add additional variables in the same scope or change optimization settings the ordering could potentially change.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of `a` and `b` in `sequence` **must** be contiguous. Furthermore the address of the first element of `a` must be the same as the address of an instance of the `struct`.

An implementation can add *padding* between `a` and `b`, and after `b`.

You cannot use pointer arithmetic to determine if there is no padding between `a` and `b`: the behaviour of pointer arithmetic is only defined within arrarys. So the behaviour of the code you present that runs `i` up to 5 is undefined, and you therefore can't use it for any reliable purpose.

Because it's legal to set a pointer to one beyond an array (or an object, but that's not relevant here), the expression `(void*)(&a + 1)` is valid, so you could use the test

```
(void*)(&a + 1) == (void*)&b;
```

to test for the contiguity or otherwise of `a` and `b`. (Acknowledge @EricPostpischil.)

Comment: Re: “You cannot use pointer arithmetic to determine if there is no padding between”; `(void *) (&a + 1) == (void *) &b` is a valid expression in C which is true if and only if `b` happens to immediately follow `a` in the address space (C 2018 6.5.9 6).